# Append options to drop down box?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-select, dropdown

I'm working on my project where I want to put drop down box and input text field in the same td tag. Here is my current code:

```
<td >
    <label class="avbHide">
    <select id="test" name="test">
        <option value="">--Select User--</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="" id="block" class="email" value=""  placeholder="example@gmail.com" title="Enter email please."/>
    </label>                                
</td>
```

JQuery code that I use to populate dropdown box:

```
var studValues = [];

studValues.push({'idOne':"13",'idTwo':"Mike, Pears"});

studValues.push({'idOne':"16",'idTwo':"Steven, Reed"});

studValues.push({'idOne':"14",'idTwo':"John, Cook"});


for(var i=0; i < studValues.length; i++){
    $('#test').append('<option value='+studValues[i].idOne+'>'+studValues[i].idTwo+'</option>');
}
```

So I tried to use this code and my drop down never get populated. Then I created select tag outside of td tag and my drop down was populated. I'm confused, why that would not work with my current code when I place select inside of td where I have my text field. Is there any rule that I have to put them in separate tag? In my case I have to put them in same td tag.

Comment: maybe its the "<option vlaue"> type when appending?

Comment: I tried and still does not work...

Comment: why is it `<option vlaue>` instead of `<option value>`?

Comment: Typo .... I will fix now.

Comment: I think you have an extra `j` in your code in `$j('#test')` just remove it and it should work as expected `$('#test')`

Comment: That is a PowerSchool tag for JQuery. I tried in jsfiddle and does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to do it on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nrx02nwg/

It should be $ instead $j, don't you think?

```
for(var i=0; i < studValues.length; i++){
    $('#test').append('<option value='+studValues[i].idOne+'>'+studValues[i].idTwo+'</option>');
}
```